# 'Bad Request' when inner class instance from Apex to LWC

Tags: apex, json, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class

I'm working on a Lightning Web Component which calls an API from Apex and display the response in the component with the help of a wrapper class.
The response is displaying correctly in the apex method. But once it is returned to the LWC's JavaScript method, it throws the following error:-

```
"{"ok":false,"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","body":{}}"
```

**LWC**

```
myMethod(event) {
    myMethod({ accountId: this.recordId, name: event.detail.value })
    .then((result) => {     
        console.log(result); // NEVER EXECUTED
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error = ' + JSON.stringify(error)); // EXECUTED
    });
}
```

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled   
public static Api.ResultWrapper myMethod(Id accountId, String name) {
    Api.ResultWrapper  result = doThing(accountId, name);
    System.debug('result = ' + result); // CORRECT RESULT
    return result;
}
```

**Api.ResultWrapper**

```
public with sharing class Api {

    // INNER

    public class ResultWrapper {
        private String hiddenProperty;
        private Map<String, String> attributes;


        @AuraEnabled
        public String getProperty() {
            return hiddenProperty;
        }


        @AuraEnabled
        public String getAccountName() {
            return attributes.get('name');
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine when I serialize the response in apex and return it as a JSON string to the javascript. 
I would like to know if there is a better solution for this issue other than the serialization workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate @AuraEnabled the properties of wrapper class

```
@AuraEnabled   
public static Api.ResultWrapper myMethod(Id accountId, String name) {
```

Here you are returning `Api.ResultWrapper`, meaning this is the data type that you want to read in javascript(lightning). If the properties of this data type are not Aura Enabled, it cannot be sent in the response. If you were using `getProperty` or `getAccountName` method and returning String, you will get it BUT if you want to return wrapper, you need aura enabled properties in that wrapper class and properties need to be `public` or `global`

```
public class ResultWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled private String hiddenProperty;
    @AuraEnabled private Map<String, String> attributes;
```

Also, you are getting `"{"ok":false,"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","body":{}}"` because you are using `attributes.get('name')` but actually not setting proper attributes value before returning. Remove method `getAccountName` or pass proper value (through `ResultWrapper` constructor) to attributes

Comment: I've already annotated the properties in the wrapper class

Comment: Can u show wrapper class also

Comment: U need to annotate private variables

Comment: But the @AuraEnabled methods should take care of accessing them. right?

Comment: edited answer. You are not using those methods but returning the wrapper data type, so properties of that data type (wrapper) need to be aura enabled

Comment: @dennisjsk Re: AuraEnabled methods -- no, that won't work. The properties themselves must be annotated in order for this to work.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I was able to fix this issue by initialising the attributes map in the wrapper class as follows. 
`private Map<String, String> attributes = new Map<String, String>();`

Comment: welcome. PLs mark as accepted if solved